# Passing Azure App Service Application Settings to SPA JS-application

Tags: azure, iis, azure-web-app-service, single-page-application

Case: The solution consists of two Web Apps configured in Azure App Service. The first one hosts a backend API (Asp.Net Core) and the second one an SPA frontend website.

In this project we decided to drop the application server(Kestrel/Node.JS) altogether from the frontend Web App, since there is no real need for that. Application is a simple Single Page Application which can be hosted directly from IIS. The application itself works perfectly. However, now when we are implementing our CI/CD-pipe we have faced an issue. The same build needs to work in both QA and Production environments. But how can we pass the API-address from Azure App Service Application Settings to the SPA-application which is running in the browser when there is no Application Server and therefore serverside code?

We can't modify the Continuous Integration -pipe - the build needs to be exactly the same in both environments. However, we could in theory add one step to the end of our Continuous Delivery -pipe and e.g. modify web.config to pass Custom Headers or add a static file that tells what environment is in question and read that from the application, but I'm not sure if that's the right way to go. Is there any App Service Extension or feature I'm unaware of which would allow passing variables from Azure App Service to the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we opted for, is reading out a json settings file which we set with a deploy step.

So in your codebase you have a file which always get read by the application with a default dev setting.

In our VSTS setup we use the 'Azure App Service Deploy'-task for deploying the code.

In that same task you have a section that is called 'File Transforms & variable Substition Option'. The XML stuff is for web.config only but for the JSON variable substitution portion you can specify file names.

Comment: just found this post explaining some of the details http://blog.bennymichielsen.be/2017/07/27/managing-settings-for-an-angular-app-with-vsts/